# codeigniter - initializing a class from a library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had a model that had an unrelated class defined inside of it.
I was prototyping and didn't spend time to create it properly.
Now that the prototype was accepted by my end users, I'm revisiting and I would like to reorg my code properly. The class looks something like this:

```
   <?php

        class myclassABC 
        {

           private $_hostname;
           private $_password;
           private $_username;
           private $_connection;
           private $_data;
           private $_timeout;
           private $_prompt;

           public function __construct($hostname, $password, $username = "", $timeout = 10) 
           {

             $this->_hostname = $hostname;
             $this->_password = $password;
             $this->_username = $username;
             $this->_timeout = $timeout;
            } // __construct


           public function connect() 
           {
           } 

           public function dosomethingelse() 
           {
           } 

        }//end class
```

I've moved all this code into a separate file, and this file is now in my libraries folder.  But i'm having problems figuring out how to properly instantiate an object in my model. 
I tried:

```
        //pass all the data we need as an array of parameters.
        $params = array('_hostname' => '$ip', '_password' => 'password', '_username' => '');
        $hp = $this->load->library($classname,$params ); 
        $hp->connect();
        $data= $hp->dosomethingelse();
        $hp->close();
```

It's loading the right class, but I'm getting the following error message:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 2 for HP5406_ssh::__construct(), called in
>   /var/www/m.racktables/system/core/Loader.php on line 1095 and defined
>
> Filename: libraries/HP5406_ssh.php
>
> Line Number: 22

Argument two is the password.
Sorry, this is my first attempt at using libraries with codeigniter.
if you could provide some suggestions, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: "Argument *two* is the password."? How to detect what's nth value in an associated array in php? I think it's not possible (it does sound absurd). Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the constructor was not expecting an array.  Which is what I am passing, based on the example in the codeigniter manual under the libraries section. i changed my constructor to accept an array and now it works. 
I'm going to post another question to see how I can pass individual parms.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a reason you need to pass individual params? Is that just your own personal reason or is there a technical one?

Comment: It's because I want to be able to reuse this class outside of CI solutions.  Aka.  I have other solutions that also rely on this class... but they instantiate the "traditional" way...

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't pass an array in said other solutions?

Comment: no... other than the fact that i don't want to have to go back and change code that's currently working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
$hp = $this->load->library($classname,$params ); //switch model name must be capitalized.
$hp->connect();
$data= $hp->dosomethingelse();
$hp->close();
```

Do this:

```
$this->load->library($classname, $params);
$classname = strtolower($classname); // get the classname to lowercase for CI
$this->$classname->connect();
$data = $this->$classname->dosomethingelse();
$this->$classname->close();
```

CodeIgniter loads the library class instance into `$this`. It's kind of strange, but it's consistent with the way the rest of CI works. If you don't like this method, you can always just `include()` or `require()` the class and use it the 'normal' way.

See the documentation for [Creating Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Here's the relevant portion:

> From within any of your Controller functions you can initialize your
>   class using the standard:
>   `$this->load->library('someclass');`
>
> Where someclass is the file name, without the ".php" file extension.
>   You can submit the file name capitalized or lower case. CodeIgniter
>   doesn't care.
>
> Once loaded you can access your class using the ***lower case*** version:
>   `$this->someclass->some_function();  // Object instances will always be lower case`

Comment: Brendan, thanks for the suggestion.  But that doesn't seem to work. getting the message:
Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object in /var/www/myapp/application/models/my_model.php on line 84

Comment: I left in $classname for illustrative purposes, but you should use the classname in its place, i.e. hp5406_ssh. Remember the reference will be in all lowercase, so you might be able to use $classname = strtolower($classname); and retain use of $classname.

Comment: hey brendan...i wanted to make this dynamic so I need to keep $classname as a variable, instead of hardcoding it.  the thing is, the class name will be passed in to me as an argument.

Comment: I guess I will have to revisit this design if I cannot use a varialbe for the class name...

Comment: So use `strtolower` so that it CI can use it.

Comment: @dot may be you can make use of `eval`

Comment: I would strongly recommend **against** the use of `eval`

Comment: I think the problem is that the constructor is not expecting an array.  Whereas, $params is an array.  I'm gonig to test that theory by changing my constructor...

Comment: That's the problem.  you'll notice that the $params variable is an array.  But the constructor is expecting individual vars.  I changed the constructor to accept an array and that resolved it.  Except, i don't want to change it to array.  Can I pass individual vars to a library?